# Removing Specific Object In Array Based On Property?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops

I have an array of drink toppings and want to remove the ones that aren't relevant to the drink, this is the code I have, but I can't figure out how to remove the topping from the array if it isn't within the criteria.

I can only remove at index path and this can change if we added more toppings etc so didn't seem accurate?

```
for toppings in self.toppings {
    if self.selectedDrink.name == "Tea" {
        if toppings.limit == "C" {
            self.toppings.remove(at: toppings)
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially if the user selected Tea it looks for toppings limited for coffee and then I need to remove those ones that respond to the "C" property, but I can't see how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why not simply try the `filter` function?

Comment: how would that look?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do in-place removal with a `for` loop, but it would be tricky, because you would need to iterate back to avoid disturbing indexes.

A simpler approach is to filter the array, and assign it back to the `toppings` property, like this:

```
toppings = toppings.filter {$0.limit != "C"}
```