# How to remove an element from array of object on swift based on id?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a array of objects such as.

```
var arrStudents = [S1,S2,S3,S4,S5]
```

Here s1 is object of student class

```
class Student {

    var id:Int!
    var name:String!
    var address:String?
    var phone:Int!
}
```

Now I want to delete a record from array by the the student id. please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your class instances starting with a lowercase letter. Btw you should avoid as much as possible the use of implicitly unwrapped optionals specially if you don't understand how optionals work. All you need is to provide your class a custom initializer or just use a struct instead of a class which doesn't require you to implement an initializer

Comment: Note that you should define your telephone property as String type

Comment: `I want to learn all array operations` - there are plenty of tutorials over the internet for this. Here on SO we deal with concrete problems.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback @LeoDabus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Specific Object In Array Based On Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614661/removing-specific-object-in-array-based-on-property)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Specific Object In Array Based On Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614661/removing-specific-object-in-array-based-on-property)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

loop through all the indexes of the array and check if the id you want to delete matches, if yes it will filter out and you can remove that index :-)

```
let idToDelete = 10
if let index = arrStudents.index(where: {$0.id == idToDelete}) {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

if you want to remove multiple value in single iteration you should start the loop from last index to first index, so it will not crash (out of bound error )

```
var idsToDelete = [10, 20]
for id in idsToDelete {
        for (i,str) in arrStudents.enumerated().reversed()
        {
            if str.id == id
            {
                arrStudents.remove(at: i)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Btw Swift is a type inferred language. No need to explicitly set the type. `self` is redundant. Where is temp object declared?

Comment: Opps sorry still objective-c style stuck with self. thanks for your comments :-)

Comment: `index(where:)` is now deprecated. The new method is `firstIndex(where:)`

Answer (score 1):

First Veriables name should be lower case.

Just Search for index of searching element in the array using property `id` and then remove it from student array.

```
var arrStudents = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]


if let index = arrStudents.index(where: {$0.id == 1}) // Search id = 1 you can set any value 
{
    arrStudents.remove(at: index)
}
```

To learn Refers below Examples:

1. [Higher order functions in swift: Filter, Map, Reduce, flatmap](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8)
2. [Simple Higher Order Functions in Swift 3.0 — Map, filter, reduce and flatMap!](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/simple-higher-order-functions-in-swift-3-0-map-filter-reduce-and-flatmap-984fa00b2532)
3. [Swift Guide to Map Filter Reduce](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Stu {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
    }

    let stu1 = Stu(id: 1, name: "Tom")
    let stu2 = Stu(id: 2, name: "Jhon")

    var arrString: [Stu] = [stu1, stu2]

    //filter will give you an array with the matched value
    let matchedObjectFromArray = arrString.filter { (obj) -> Bool in
        return obj.id == 1 //return Stu object whose id = 1
    }

    //index method gives index of object if found in an array otherwise gives nil
    if let indexOfObject = arrString.index(where: { (obj) -> Bool in
        return obj.id == 2 // return index of Stu object whose id = 2
    }) {

        let removedObject = arrString.remove(at: indexOfObject)
        print(removedObject.id)
    }
```