# Remove element from array if the element contains string

Tags: swift

I am trying to remove an element from an array if the element contains a keyword, but I could not any examples for this, how would be able to achieve something like that in Swift 4?

Here is a code example to make my question clearer.

Say I have this array:

```
let arr = ["123Example","Testing","876.123"]
```

How can I remove the string that have `123` in them to make the array just `["Testing"]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Specific Object In Array Based On Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614661/removing-specific-object-in-array-based-on-property)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter` combined with `String.contains` to keep only the elements of the array of strings that doesn't contain the keyword.

```
let keyword = "123"
let stringsWithoutKeyword = arr.filter({!$0.contains(keyword)}) //["Testing"]
```